# Quantification logic

Tags: logic

Hotels are both expensive and depressing. Some hotels are shabby. Therefore
some expensive things are shabby. I symbolized this as $\forall x[H(x) \implies (E(x)\vee D(x))] ,\; \exists x\; (H(x) \wedge S(x))\vdash (∃x)(E(x)\wedge S(x))$.

Is my symbolization correct? I also found out that this argument is invalid. Am i wrong?

Last question, how will i symbolize this?

A book is interesting only if it is well written. A book is well written only if it is interesting. Therefore, any book is both interesting and well written if it is either interesting or well written.

Comment: For the first sentence you wrote the conclusion as "Ex V Dx" which I assume means "or"; it should be "and". Otherwise, your symbolization is correct. If you had written it as "and" it would be a valid argument. // For the second part, "$p$ only if $q$" means $p\supset q$.

Comment: I don't see why that argument is invalid.

Comment: @fleablood ahh that was my fault. While retexing the post I absentmindedly fixed the error.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  The argument is valid even if the symbolizing is faulty.  And now that you've had the symbolism corrected maybe you should edit the OP.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x\;\Big(H(x) \to \big(E(x)\color{red}{\wedge} D(x)\big)\Big) ,\; \exists x\; \big(H(x) \wedge S(x)\big)\;\vdash \;\exists x\;\big(E(x)\wedge S(x)\big)$ is a valid argument.

---

> A book is interesting only if it is well written. A book is well written only if it is interesting. Therefore, any book is both interesting and well written if it is either interesting or well written.

The first sentence may be written as either: $\forall x\;\Big(\big(B(x)\wedge I(x)\big)\,\to\, W(x)\Big)\\ \forall x\;\Big(B(x)\,\to\,\big(I(x)\to W(x)\big)\Big)$

The equivalence is due to the Rule of Exportation.   I think the second form makes this argument clearer.

The second sentence is similar, and the third not *much* different.

The argument is *basically*: $P\to Q, Q\to P \;\vdash\; \textsf{...what goes here?}$

Do you think this is valid?